# Fill Edit Texts in one go

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've 3 `EditText of maxlength=1` that I want to fill in a sequential manner.
That is user types 3 chars simultaneously, then 3 edit text will be filled.
Idea was to to put these 3 editText in a `ArrayList` & what user enters in a separate arraylist.

when user selects an EditText, its `TextWatcher's  afterTextChanged` will be called & then the character will be inserted in the arraylist.

Then a loop will be stated on the size of character list and for each element in the arraylist, corresponding edittext will be picked up & filled.

something like:

```
 private TextWatcher myTextChangeListener = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            EditText editText = null;
            if (mCharList.size() < 3) {
                mCharList.add(editable.toString());
            }
            if (mCharList.size() > 0) {
                for (int index = 0; index < mCharList.size(); index++) {
                    editText = myETList.get(index);
                    editText.setText(mCharList.get(index));
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

But as soon as the `editText.setText(mCharList.get(index));` is called afterTextChanged() is called again & and infinite loop starts, cusing StackOverFlow exception.

Also how should I handle delete/backspace key event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the class EditText in this way:

```
//Declaration
   private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

    private View view;
       private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
           this.view = view;
       }

       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            String text = editable.toString();
            switch(view.getId()){
                case R.id.name:
                    model.setName(text);
                    break;
                case R.id.email:
                    model.setEmail(text);
                    break;
                case R.id.phone:
                    model.setPhone(text);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

If you know who write you can avoid it to work and stop your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
       @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

     if (mCharList.size() < 3) {
            mCharList.add(editable.toString());
        }
        if (mCharList.size() > 0) {
            for (int index = 0; index < mCharList.size(); index++) {
                editText = myETList.get(index);
                editText.setText(mCharList.get(index));
            }
        }

    }
```